# Number of available seats

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines, gds

is there a way to get access to a number of empty seats at different airlines? how do I get this data?

**Edit:** my question is if the OTA's have this access? do they know at every moment how many tickets are left in each class? do they get this data from the GDS?

if not - how can I get (as an OTA) this access?

Comment: General passenger loading numbers are commercially sensitive so I don't see why airlines would make this information public.

Comment: The OTAs get the booking class availability information shown in the linked duplicate question. They don't get data on the actual number of seats available, which is a slightly different question, since airlines keep that for themselves. It sounds like your question is about developing software for an OTA, and that unfortunately is going to be off-topic here, since running an OTA is beyond the scope of what this site covers.

Answer (score 0):

As the mentioned potential duplicate shows, there is no direct way.

You can start booking tickets on the airline's site in multiple browser windows in parallel (keeping them all open and uncompleted), until no more tickets are shown available, but it is a bit tedious, and it might not work for all airlines, depending on how they handle the blocking.

Comment: on the airline's own site, they typically block it temporarily. I'll edit to clarify. I often do it on Southwest, to see how full my flight will be.